# AngularJS: how put correct model to repeated radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I think I have some sort of special code here as all I could google was "too simple" for my problem and it also didn't helped to come to a solution by myself, sadly.
I got a radio button group of 2 radios. I am iterating over "type" data from the backend to create the radio buttons.
My problem is the data binding: When I want to edit an object its "type" is set correctly, but not registered by the view so it doesn't select the desired option.

**Follwing my situation:**
Backend providing me this as "typeList":

```
[
 {"text":"cool option","enumm":"COOL"},
 {"text":"option maximus","enumm":"MAX"}
]
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<span ng-repeat="type in typeList track by type.enumm">
    <input 
         type="radio" 
         name="type" required 
         ng-model="myCtrl.object.type" 
         ng-value="type">
    {{type.text}}
</span>
```

**Some Explanation**
I don't want to use "naked" texts, I want to use some sort of identifier - in this case it is an enum. The chosen value shall be the entire "type", not only "type.text" as the backend expects type, and not a simple String.
So all I do with this is always a package thingy, the type.text is for like formatted/internationlized text etc.

A Pre-Selection works by setting this in the controller: `this.object.type = typeList[0];`
The first radio button is already selected, wonderful.

But why isn't it selected when editing the object. I made a "log" within the HTML with `{{myCtrl.object.type}}` and the result is `{"text":"cool option","enumm":"COOL"}`. The very same like when pre selecting. I already work with the same "technique" using select inputs, and it works fine. I also found some google results saying "use $parent because of parent/child scope". But 1) I didn't get that straight and 2) think it is not the problem here, as I use a controllers scope and not the $scope, or is this thinking wrong?

It might be explained badly, sorry if so, but I hope someone 1) get's what I want and 2) knows a solution for it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to bind to elements from an array, I believe you need to assign the actual elements from the array to your model property.

So this creates a new obj and sets it to `$scope.selectedType` (not what you want):

```
$scope.selectedType = {"text":"cool option","enumm":"COOL"};
```

whereas this assigns the first element of the array (which is what you want)

```
$scope.selectedType = $scope.typeList[0];
```

So to change the model, you can lookup the entry from the array and assign it to your model with something like this

```
$scope.selectedType = $scope.typeList.filter(...)
```

Here's a quick example of this approach http://plnkr.co/edit/wvq8yH7WIj7rH2SBI8qF

Comment: First of all, thanks for your effort! Unfortunately your plunker did'nt help me, but I tried to use your idea of fetching the correct array element.
And I'm glad, that **worked**! Which is both nice and also annoyning, why can't I use my already filled model? Because what I now do is this:

`if(!self.object.type) {
    self.object.type = $scope.typeList[0];
} else {
    self.object.type = _.filter($scope.typeList, self.object.type)[0];
}`

but okay, as it works it's enough for me :)
Thank you!